# mvn --version says permission denied

Tags: permissions, apache2, maven-3

I have extracted the maven binary files to my home directory i.e `/home/pranish` then ran the following commands to install maven environment variables:

```
export M2_HOME=/home/pranish/apache-maven-3.3.3
```

and

```
export PATH=/home/pranish/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:${PATH}
```

Then when I execute `mvn --verison` command, it gives me an error:

```
bash: /home/pranish/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn: Permission denied
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says

```
bash: /home/pranish/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn: Permission denied
```

That means, you have no access/executable rights for the file.

Correct the access rights of your home folder:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER
chmod +x /home/$USER/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn
```

---

*Explanation*

- `sudo`

  You are probably not the owner for some files, therefore you need `sudo` rights to change owner
- `chown -R`

  The command to change the owner recursively. All files in your home folder are your files and only your files
- `chmod +x`

  The command to set the executable rights
- `$USER:$USER`

  Per default in Ubuntu the owner and the group are the same in your home folder and `$USER` is your username. Try this with `echo $USER`
- `/home/pranish`

  Your home folder, the same as `~` or `/home/$USER`

Comment: Please explain me what will it do. I am new to linux and if I run any command, it might bring changes in the system which I wont know

Comment: Update my answer